# How to use Foursquare SDK in android

Tags: android

I am doing an application that requires the Facebook and Foursquare Login.For that I am using android SDk for Facebook
IS there any SDK for foursquare in android like we have facebook SDK for android.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [These OpenSource](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/Foursquare/CatalogFoursquare.htm) Projects and FourSquare API.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Foursquare api page. They are having an API which you can use.

here: http://developer.foursquare.com/

Answer (score 0):

At the moment there are no official Android SDKs from Foursquare.

You can take a look at this open source project https://github.com/condesales/easyFoursquare4Android. It uses oauth2 with a webview on android to capture user token. There are some requests tasks already implemented like searchVenues and checkins.